# how to display to action of each combo box value in single tkinter window using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I write the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Frame, Entry, Button, StringVar
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

root = Tk()
paper = StringVar()    

def main_fn(event):
    value = event.widget.get()
    if(value=="1"):
        button = Button(root,text = "Button 1",font="rockwell", bg=
                        "pale goldenrod")
        button.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5,ipadx=5,sticky=(E+W))

        button2 = Button(root,text="Button 2", font="rockwell",
                         bg= "pale goldenrod")
        button2.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=5,sticky=(E+W))
        
        button3 = Button(root, text ="Button 3",font="rockwell",
                         bg ="pale goldenrod")
        button3.grid(row=4,column=1,pady=5,sticky=(W+E))
        
        button4 = Button(root, text="Button 4",font="rockwell",
                         bg="pale goldenrod")
        button4.grid(row=5,column=1,pady=5,sticky=(W+E))
        
    elif(value=="2"):

        button = Button(root,text = "Button 1",font="rockwell", bg=
                        "pale goldenrod")
        button.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5,ipadx=5,sticky=(E+W))
        
        button2 = Button(root,text="Button 2", font="rockwell",
                         bg= "pale goldenrod")
        button2.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=5,sticky=(E+W))
        
    
label = Label(root,text="Select your choice",font="rockwell",relief="ridge",
              bg="pale goldenrod")
label.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=5,sticky=(E+W),ipadx=5)

choose_np = Combobox(root,textvariable = paper,font=("rockwell",11))
choose_np['values']= ('1','2','3','4')
choose_np.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=5,sticky=(W+E),ipadx=5)
choose_np.current()
choose_np.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>" , main_fn)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to perform some action on each combo box value, but the result of each value should be displayed on single window. If user select the value 1, the the result of 1 should be displayed on root window and again if user select value 2 then the result of the value 2 should be displayed on the same window and the result of value 1 should be cleared from the window.

*So, only the result of the selected value should be displayed on a single window.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so i am come up with a solution. A frame can be used to display different content on different value selected.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Frame, Entry, Button, StringVar
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=2,column=1)
paper = StringVar()    

def main_fn(event):
    value = event.widget.get()
    if(value=="1"):
        for widget in frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        button = Button(frame,text = "Button 1",font="rockwell", bg=
                        "pale goldenrod")
        button.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5,ipadx=5,sticky=(E+W))

        button2 = Button(frame,text="Button 2", font="rockwell",
                         bg= "pale goldenrod")
        button2.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=5,sticky=(E+W))
        
        button3 = Button(frame, text ="Button 3",font="rockwell",
                         bg ="pale goldenrod")
        button3.grid(row=4,column=1,pady=5,sticky=(W+E))
        
        button4 = Button(frame, text="Button 4",font="rockwell",
                         bg="pale goldenrod")
        button4.grid(row=5,column=1,pady=5,sticky=(W+E))
        
    elif(value=="2"):
        for widget in frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        button = Button(frame,text = "Button 1",font="rockwell", bg=
                        "pale goldenrod")
        button.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5,ipadx=5,sticky=(E+W))
        
        button2 = Button(frame,text="Button 2", font="rockwell",
                         bg= "pale goldenrod")
        button2.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=5,sticky=(E+W))
    elif(value=="3"):
        for widget in frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
    
label = Label(root,text="Select your choice",font="rockwell",relief="ridge",
              bg="pale goldenrod")
label.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=5,sticky=(E+W),ipadx=5)

choose_np = Combobox(root,textvariable = paper,font=("rockwell",11))
choose_np['values']= ('1','2','3','4')
choose_np.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=5,sticky=(W+E),ipadx=5)
choose_np.current()
choose_np.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>" , main_fn)

root.mainloop()
```

Add a frame in root window where you want to change the content. **widget.destroy()** is used to clear the content of previous value selected.